# Common colour and legend for multiple categorical rasters

Tags: legend, raster, categorical-data

I want to make a multipanel plot of 3 rasters with categorical values. is there a way where I can automatically draw breaks, and colors for each raster? I have a reproducible example below with three rasters r1,r2, and r3.
r1 has values from 0to 5, r2 has values 0,13,4 and r3 has values 0,1,2,4. I want to save myself from specifying the color panel for each raster separately.

Thanks in advance

```
library(raster)

# Define the rasters
r1 <- raster(nrow=5, ncol=5)
x1<- c(0,1,2,3,4,5)
values(r1) <- sample(x1, ncell(r1), replace=TRUE)

r2 <- raster(nrow=5, ncol=5)
x2<- c(0,1,3,4)
values(r2) <- sample(x2, ncell(r2), replace=TRUE)
as.factor(r2)

r3 <- raster(nrow=5, ncol=5)
x3<- c(0,1,2,4)
values(r3) <- sample(x3, ncell(r3), replace=TRUE)
as.factor(r3)


# creating the breaks and colour vectors

br1    <- c(0,1,2,3,4,5)
cl1    <- c("red","orange","green","blue","gray", "brown")

br2    <- c(0,1,3,4)
cl2    <- c("red","orange","blue","gray")

br3    <- c(0,1,2,4)
cl3    <- c("red","orange","green","brown")


# Create the multi plot
par(mfrow=c(1,3),xpd=T)

plot(r1,col=cl1,legend=F,axes=F,asp=NA)
text(r1,cex=1)
plot(r1,legend.only=T, breaks=br1,col = cl1,bty="n",xpd=T)


plot(r2,col=cl2,legend=F,axes=F,asp=NA)
text(r2,cex=1)
plot(r2,legend.only=T, breaks=br2,col = cl2,bty="n",xpd=T)

plot(r3, col=cl3,legend=F,axes=F,asp=NA)
text(r3, cex=1)
plot(r3, legend.only=T, breaks=br3,col = cl3,bty="n",xpd=T)
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be more efficient ways to plot raster panels or facets, e.g. ?plot::raster suggests that the rasterVis package offers more advanced plotting functions for raster objects, including trellis/lattice plots.

However, the following solution aims at avoiding repeated code as indicated in your question and stays close to the original. Here, a custom function and lists, as well as lapply(), are used.

```r
library(raster)

# Define the rasters
r1 <- raster(nrow = 5, ncol = 5)
x1 <- c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
values(r1) <- sample(x1, ncell(r1), replace = TRUE)

br1    <- c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
cl1    <- c("red", "orange", "green", "blue", "gray", "brown")

r2 <- raster(nrow = 5, ncol = 5)
x2 <- c(0, 1, 3, 4)
values(r2) <- sample(x2, ncell(r2), replace = TRUE)
r2_2 <- r2
as.factor(r2) # as.factor() does not modify the object r2 in place.
identical(r2, r2_2) 

r3 <- raster(nrow = 5, ncol = 5)
x3 <- c(0, 1, 2, 4)
values(r3) <- sample(x3, ncell(r3), replace = TRUE)

# creating the breaks and colour vectors

br1    <- c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
cl1    <- c("red", "orange", "green", "blue", "gray", "brown")

raster_list_1 <- list(r1, br1, cl1)

br2    <- c(0, 1, 3, 4)
cl2    <- c("red", "orange", "blue", "gray")

raster_list_2 <- list(r2, br2, cl2)

br3    <- c(0, 1, 2, 4)
cl3    <- c("red", "orange", "green", "brown")

raster_list_3 <- list(r3, br3, cl3)

raster_listoflists <-
  list(raster_list_1, raster_list_2, raster_list_3)

# Create the multi plot
plot_raster_panels <- function(rasterlists) {
  list_size <- length(rasterlists)
  mfrow_before <- par("mfrow")
  par(mfrow = c(1, list_size), xpd = TRUE)
  lapply(rasterlists, function(x) {
    raster_layer <- x[[1]]
    breaks <- x[[2]]
    colours <- x[[3]]
    
    plot(
      raster_layer,
      col = colours,
      legend = FALSE,
      axes = FALSE,
      asp = NA
    )
    text(raster_layer, cex = 1)
    plot(
      raster_layer,
      legend.only = TRUE,
      breaks = breaks,
      col = colours,
      bty = "n",
      xpd = TRUE
    )
  })
  on.exit(par(mfrow = mfrow_before))
  invisible(0)
}

plot_raster_panels(raster_listoflists)
```

Some remarks and suggestions:

- I would advise you to aim for a consistent coding style, e.g. don't mix `argument = T` and `argument = TRUE`. You should probably avoid using `T` and `F` altogether, as they are just aliases to `TRUE` and `FALSE` respectively and can be reassigned by users.
- Use instructive names for variables. No one, not even you in a few months, is going to remember what br1 and cl1 stand for. Use descriptive verbs for functions and nouns that describe content for objects and `snake_case` for objects, as suggested in [Tidyverse Style Guide](https://style.tidyverse.org/).
- You use `as.factor(raster_object)` in your script but do not assign it. If you want to inspect the result interactively, this is fine. However, be aware that most R functions do not modify objects in place, i.e. the objects are *immutable*, and you have to assign the result to a new object. A notable exception to this is the `R6` package and its functions ([Advanced R - R6](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/r6.html)).
- I am using lists in my solution and not vectors because lists can, as opposed to vectors, hold different types of data (cf. [An Introduction to R - Lists](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Lists)).
- It is not possible to save the plot of R base plot functions directly into an object since they return `NULL` or computed values instead (e.g. `(plot(1))`). To avoid printing `NULL` to the console, I have used `invisible(0)` to return an arbitrary number (0 is, however, conventionally used in function returns to signal normal execution).
- Since we want to keep the plot after the function has run, we can't turn off the graphic device (`dev.off()`) inside our function. Thus we should reset the `mfrow` parameter that we changed for the multi-panel plot.

Edit: Edited for clarity, added syntax highlighting and references.